# Respect CSS @import when building app with gulp-useref

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, gulp

I use jQuery UI in my project and build it with gulp. I include its styles in the following way:

```
<!-- build:css styles/vendor/jqueryui.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When I build it with [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-useref) plugin, it changes to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor/jqueryui.css"/>
```

The problem is that the contents of the `styles/vendor/jqueryui.css` looks like this:

```
@import "jquery.ui.base.css";@import "jquery.ui.theme.css";
```

These imports obviously fail in distribution package, because there are no `jquery.ui.base.css` and `jquery.ui.theme.css` files. They weren't moved to the dist package from `bower_components/jqueryui/themes/base/`.

How to include the jQuery UI theme correctly **without** specifying all `jquery.*.css` files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gulp, you should be building your jQuery UI styles **FIRST** then piping the vendor styles to a build directory. That way you have a compiled CSS that doesn't expose your source (bower_components). If you don't need ALL the jQuery styles, build the ones you need explicitly in a separate gulp task, then pipe it into your main styles or continue with the rest of the build. This might be important for you if there is a dependency chain.

TL;DR your HTML should only be linking to compiled styles, not source.